# Visual Studio - Is there a keyboard combination to select an entire line?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

I already know about <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to delete an entire line...is there one to just select an entire line (which I can then copy and paste somewhere else...)

Comment: i don't think i follow...

for example if i want to add a new asp insert parameter, i often just copy/paste a similar one, and change the name.  whats wrong with that?

Comment: sorry assumed your working in C# (often forget VS is used for web dev.).

Comment: I'm normally in VB.NET...I just don't know much about refactoring I guess

Comment: @Albert I don't know if ASP.NET has snippet support, IIRC they didn't have before, but snippets are also a nice way of repeating a similar concept. Look up snippets if you haven't already since this post.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to cut an entire line. Similarly, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> to copy an entire line.

As long as you don't have anything selected, the command will work on the entire line.

Comment: You can also use Shift-Del to cut the line, and Ctrl-Insert to copy it.

Comment: Cool, I just found that `Ctrl C` can copy whole line in Visual Studio WITHOUT highlight whole line! thanks

Comment: Alas this doesn't work as expected when word wrap is enabled. Please vote for the bug report at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/138259/cut-command-should-delete-logical-line.html

Comment: Those work well until you want to replace the line with text copied previously and still want keep initial copy. Ctrl+v inserts the text, If you delete line using Ctrl + v the copy is lost.

Answer (score 53):

Hit

- <kbd>Home</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>

Comment: You don't need to select to copy the current line, can just go CTRL+C then CTRL+V if there's no current selection as state already, though normally I do this too

Comment: While the OP had mentioned that he commonly needs to select the line to then copy/paste somewhere else, this is an answer to the question as given. Sometimes you do need to select the line and don't intend to copy (ex, in preparation for a 'surround with...' execution).

Comment: What action is this called? My short cuts got overridden

Answer (score 23):

You can do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>DownArrow</kbd>.

Comment: Shift + DownArrow only works if the cursor is currently at the beginning of the line.

Comment: This will also select any text up to the cursor position from the line below.

Answer (score 9):

Yes there is. If you are in the begining of the line press Shift+ End. 
If you are in the end of the line press Shift+ Home. 
Hope that helps

Comment: I think you mean Shift + Home/End? Ctrl + End will go to the end of the document.

Answer (score 6):

I believe, if you don't have any selection and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, it would copy the line.

Answer (score 5):

`Shift` + `End` = Select between cursor and the end of the line

Answer (score 4):

It's <kbd>Home</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> for me.

Or you change that [setting](http://codereflect.com/2010/04/11/visual-studio-2010-tips-cut-copy-operations-on-unselected-lines/) which makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> with no selection copy the line. But I hate that, so I always turn it off. (Thanks to Bala for [providing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2732098/2732152#2732152) the link to that setting!)

To *cut* a line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works in my keyboard settings.

Comment: @LnDCobra: It's a tag: `<kbd>Ctrl</kdb>`.

Answer (score 4):

There's also <kbd>Alt-Up</kbd> and <kbd>Alt-Down</kbd> to move whole lines.  It's two fewer keystrokes than using <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>, and unlike <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>, it also moves multiple *whole lines* at a time if your selection covers multiple lines even partially.  It's also nice because the feedback is instantaneous, unlike <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd> where you can never remember whether the pasted line will go above or below your cursor.

I saw this and thought I'd never use the feature.  But once I got used to it I use it all the time.  There's no easier way to move a block of code than using <kbd>Shift-Up/Down</kbd> to select the lines, press <kbd>Alt-Up/Down</kbd> a few times to move them, and then use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to adjust the indentation.

Of course it only works within the same file though.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio macros are another way to do these types of operations if you can't find an existing command.  A simple way to create one is:

- Use the Record TemporaryMacro option (under Tools/Macros).
- Select the line however you prefer (e.g., home, shift, end).
- Click Stop Recording (under Tools/Macros).
- Choose Save TemporaryMacro (under Tools/Macros).
- Then choose Tools/Customize/Keyboard and assign a shortcut to the macro.

Answer (score 3):

It's not specifically a keyboard shortcut, but a triple-click will select a whole line of code.

This works in some other areas of Windows as well. In Chrome, for example, double-click selects a word, but triple-click selects a paragraph.

(This works in Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. Not sure about other versions/platforms.)

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to copy entire line, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd> to paste entire line.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers require either using a mouse or hitting more than one combination.
So I've created a macro for those who want a VSCode-like Ctrl+L behaviour. It can select multiple lines.

To use it, install Visual Commander extension for macros: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.VisualCommander

Then create a new command, select C# as a language and paste this code:

```cs
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

public class C : VisualCommanderExt.ICommand
{
    public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
    {
        var ts = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection as EnvDTE.TextSelection;
        if (!ts.ActivePoint.AtStartOfLine)
            ts.StartOfLine();
        ts.LineDown(true, 1);
    }
}
```

Now you can assign a desired shortcut in preferences:

[image]

Tested in VS 2022.

Answer (score -1):

1. Triple-click to select the whole line. Then do what you want.
2. You can press `Home` + `Shift` + `End` to select the whole line as well.
3. If you want to copy the whole line then just press `Ctrl` + `C`. It will copy the whole line if nothing is selected.